# How can I see tips while android studio is showing off auto codes?

Tags: java, android

It's like when you Blabla.set (and there comes a bunch of codes to select)
and when you click over them I want them to show the little explanation of what the code does on the right. I could explain better with images but stackoverflow wont let me because I dont have the required honor points, which I find this requirement extremely inpractical and useless for newcomers.

Comment: you mean documentation?

Comment: Yes, I think. I already checked the "show quick doc on mouse move" but it only shows when I already typed a code. I want to see it while I am still in this position http://i.imgur.com/zp7NOoK.jpg

Comment: I'm not sure there is an option for showing more than the method signatures.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming this is a question about Android Studio or IntelliJ.

After the functions tooltip window opens, like this:

[image: Functions tooltip window]

Instead of using the mouse, navigate up/down with the arrow keys to select de desired function and then press the "Quick Documentation" shortcut (F1 on Mac).